# My website has a SSL certificate but browsers still say connection isn't safe

Tags: ssl, https

I got a SSL certificate for my server with Let's Encrypt, but when I access my website on HTTPS the browsers still say my connection is insecure. Btw, I'm running Apache on a CentOS 7. All request are redirected to the port 443 automatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: The browser will tell you why.

Comment: Yes, just found the error: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. My Common Name matches the ServerName. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

According to your last answer, you have to add new Vhost to Apache for the second domain name and generate another (one more) Let's Encrypt certificate for it.

At end you can check with :

```
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yourwebsite.com
```

if both certificates are right.

Comment: It worked for the certificate! But there's still another error: 

Active content with certificate errors
You have recently allowed content loaded with certificate errors (such as scripts or iframes) to run on this site.

Comment: But all of my external content is loading on HTTPS.

Comment: @Tomas, your code probably refer to some img/scripts or any statics links pointed to locals files but they do not begin with "https://"

Try to change all locals links starting with  "http://" by "https://"

Comment: You're right! There were some links that were not secure!

Comment: Thank you Origin!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on. I had two DNS 'A' entries pointing to different IP addresses. I deleted one of them. But I have two domains. Now one of them still shows up as insecure and the other one is okay. Both of them point to the same IP.